# Не приходят данные из формы в $_POST (PHP, Apache2)

Tags: php, post, apache2

Данные с форм, переданные методом POST, не приходят в массив $_REQUEST(ну и само собой в $_POST). Исключение из правила: action="/" в форме. Если написать любой другой экшен, то при сабмите формы, меня редиректит на указаный в экшене адрес, но $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] вернет значение "GET", а массив POST будет пустым(GET тоже пустой). В тоже время Firebug показывает, что данные пришли именно POST-ом и отображает эти данные ([скриншот](http://firepic.org/images/2016-01/19/y2gqh3yiwgzs.png)).

Этот же проект я открывал на OpenServer(Windows8) и там все работало нормально, поэтому .htaccess и правильность скрипта не вызывают сомнений.
Скорее всего это связано с конфигом apache, но что именно там не так я не догадываюсь.

У меня стоит:
Ubuntu 14.04, Apache/2.4.7, php version 5.5.9

Код формы, на всякий случай.

```
<form role="form" action="/profile/1" method="POST">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter an email" required>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pass">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter a password" required>
             </div>
             <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="yes"> Remember me</label>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Такая же пролема. Если на сервере подключаться через localhost - все работает, если же на тот же сервер заходить через внешний IP - POST из формы не попадает в скрипты. Если у ТС решилось - прошу подсказать как. Серевер apache2 система Linux Fedora 29

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сконфигурировать apache следующим образом

```
<Location />
   <LimitExcept GET HEAD POST OPTIONS DELETE PUT>
       Allow from all
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

В `php.ini` проверьте

- `track_vars` (это для старых версий - PHP 4) должен содержать `On`
- `variables_order` по умолчанию должен содержать `EGPCS`
- `post_max_size` должен содержать значение (пример. 8MB)

Проверьте в каком `enctype` передаются даные

И напоследок магия, если ничего не помогло, попробуйте значение атрибута `action` заменить на `/profile/1/`

Comment: Не помогло(   В `php.ini` все стоит как Вы указали. `enctype` дефолтный, пробовал все типы, в конфиг апача строки добавил. как и раньше, action работает только такой `"/"`.